# Is there a difference between 行くった and 行った or is the first one grammatically wrong?

Tags: conjugations, past, irregularities-exceptions

When I want to write ‘Today I went to Nagoya.’ Which one is correct?

- 今日は名古屋に行くった。
                    Or
- 今日は名古屋に行った。

Comment: The -te form of 行く is 行って. Where did you get 行くった from? You could see 行くって show up as a variant of 行くと (quoting someone saying 行く), but I don't think that would ever become った.

Comment: Are you not hesitating between 行った and 行っていた? Please, do clarify how you came up with 行くった.

Answer (score 3):

It can only be 行った. I can't think of any situation where 行くった would be meaningful.

The verb 行く is slightly irregular. Normally, for a verb ending in く you would replace  the く with いた to form the past tense. e.g. 書く -> 書いた.